# How do I do proper Structured Logging in Dropwizard

Tags: java, logback, dropwizard

I have a Dropwizard service and I am migrating it to use structured logging. I was able to get json layout to work using the library `io.dropwizard:dropwizard-json-logging` and the configuration:

```
  appenders:
    - type: console
      target: stderr
      layout:
        type: json
        timestampFormat: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
        prettyPrint: false
        appendLineSeparator: true
        includes: [timestamp, threadName, level, loggerName, message, mdc, exception]
        customFieldNames:
          timestamp: "@timestamp"
        additionalFields:
          service-name: "user-service"
        includesMdcKeys: [userId]
        flattenMdc: true
```

That all works fine but it isn't really structured logging. I still can only log messages as messages rather adding properties to the json log message.

For example, I would like to be able to log:

```
log.info("Unauthorized user", "email", userEmail)
```

and see

```
{"level":"INFO","thread":"main","message":"Unauthorized user","service-name":"user-service","@timestamp":"2023-07-21T19:39:11.748+0000", "email", "joe.smith@example.com"}
```

So that I can build dashboards for individual log messages, filter by properties, etc.

Can anyone help me do that?

Comment: Have you figured that out?

Comment: Yes. Unfortunately, I had to write something myself. The code belongs to my employer and it is not open source. I may be able to open source it but it would take a bit of work and management would have to approve it.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I also had to extend it with a custom solution in the end :).